# Lightbox to open a div

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I am using the lightbox library and I was wondering if there is away to call it via `onclick` instead of rel?

would `$(this).lightbox()` didn't work, I am trying to get lightbox to popup another page if someone clicks on a button.

---

Sorry my bad, I meant to open a div and not a new page. I am planning on using a jquery click bind event so that part is solved, just need to figure out how to open a hidden div with light box...I am using

http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Comment: Which lightbox library?

Comment: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I wrote my example before you specified which lightbox you are using. I'll leave the answer, though, in case it is useful to you.

Here is an example of using the lightbox (aka dialog) included with the jQueryUI library.  Note the tags in the `<head>` for loading the libraries, first.  Libraries must load before the code, and the jQueryUI theme should be loaded before the jQueryUI library.

Note that the lightbox replaces the DIV which I have called `#msgbox`. Upon DOM load, that DIV becomes invisible, allowing me to inject HTML and display it within a lightbox.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

        <style>
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#mybutt').click(function() {
                    $('#msgbox').html('<iframe src="http://www.stackexchange.com" width="550" height="700"></iframe>');
                    $('#msgbox').dialog('open');
                });

                $( "#msgbox" ).dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    height: 855,
                    width: 605,
                    modal: true,
                    title: 'Here is a demo:',
                    buttons: {
                        "Close page and lightbox": function() {
                            //do some stuff here
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    },
                    close: function() {
                        alert('Can do other things as lightbox is closing');
                    }
                });

            }); //END $(document).ready()

        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    <input type="button" id="mybutt" value="Click the button" />
    <div id="msgbox"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lightbox link like this:

```
<a href="image.jpg" rel="lightbox" id="my-link">My Link</a>
```

Then you can open it elsewhere with the following code:

```
$("#my-link").trigger("click");
```